# Convert.ToBase64String returns same value for different byte arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, base64

This example:

```
            var a = Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)531689).Reverse().ToArray());
            var b = Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)532105).Reverse().ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("{0} != {1}", a, b);
```

Outputs:

```
AAAAAAAIHOk= != AAAAAAAIHok=
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well

```
AAAAAAAIHOk= is not equal to AAAAAAAIHok=
---------^---                  -------^---
```

Comment: yes but it was a really fun question. at first i didn't recognize the difference but as I know how `Convert.ToBase64String()` works I knew that it is impossile the could be the same

Comment: Me, too, just had some bug where register of those string were not processed, and quick seethrough gave me illusion of equality...anyway, thanks!